# Redux state cannot update from dispatcher

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a custom hook which is like this:

```
const cl = ["table", "chair", "book"];
export function useClass() {
  const [class, setClass] = useState({ pl: cl[0] });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const customFunction = () => {
    let counter = 0;
    let ClassInterval = setInterval(() => {
      counter++;
      setClass({ pl: cl[Math.floor(Math.random() * cl.length)] });
      if (counter > 4) {
        clearInterval(gameInterval);
        dispatch(AddStudents(class.pl, "1"))
      }
    }, 200);
  };


  return { class, customFunction };
```

so my intention with this custom hook is that I generate a random value from the table after a specific time and then when it finish it will dispatch it to the store using `react-redux` but the issue is that it gives me always a wrong values when I console my store or inspect it with `redux-dev-tools`, so any idea why is that happening?

**EDIT**

My reducer is the following:

```
case ADD_CLASS:
      return {
        ...state,
        classes: state.classes.map((class) => {
          if (player.id === action.id) {
            return { ...player, cl: action.cl };
          } else {
            return player;
          }
        }),
      };
```

and here is the final State from devtools which is the initial state but added the wrong value:

[image]

and component that is using the hook:

```
    const RenderIcon = () => {
        return (
          <img
            src={
               class.pl === "table"
                ? Table
                : class.pl === "chair"
                ? Chair
                : Book
            }
          />
        );
        };

// same component
React.useEffect(()=> {
  console.log(class.pl) // correct value with the rendered icon
 console.log(mystore) // wrong value
})
```

Comment: what kind of result you got ? and what do you expect ?, Also you're clearing gameInterval, is that another interval or you've mistaken with ClassInterval ?

Comment: when I log the results in another component it shows the correct value which I need but when I dispatch that action to the state it does not  give me the correct value, so I thought that there is maybe an issue this this custom hook

Comment: Is the issue that the just-set `class.pl` from `setClass` isn't the `class.pl` you expect it to be a couple lines later when dispatching the `AddStudents` action? React state updates are asynchronous and processed *between* render cycles.

Comment: You already have devtools so what is dispatched and what changes when it is dispatched? If the wrong thing is dispatched then show full dispatch code, if state isn't written correctly then show reducer code if both are correct then show how you select the value from state on log it.

Comment: I have added changes to question, you can take a look maybe?

Comment: I see you are defining a const called ‘class’. I am pretty sure that it is a reserved keyword. This might lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @ThomasVangelooven you mean in custom hook?